# Add key value pair columns to an existing model and database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My Project have 2 models Users and posts. 
The relationship between them is user has_many posts and post belongs_to :users.

The model "Posts" that has a table with post_id, text of the post, and ref of another model User ie user_id. Now I need to add a columns of "keys" and "values" to the table of MODEL Posts. So I want to create a new table with the fields of post_id , user_id , key and value. For this do I need to create a new model ? or can I add a table to the existing model ? Any other suggestions ?

Comment: How do the key-value pairs relate to the records stored in A or B?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand questions concerning data modelling that are phrased in terms of hypothetical A's and B's. If you tell us what you're actually doing then you're likely to get a better quality of answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `has_and_belongs_to_many` option. With use of it, you do not have to create new model.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: but my relation for the model A and B is....
 
A belongs_to B and B has many A. Can I still implement this ?